# SSRS RDLC: Footer always printing an empty line on Word-Export

Tags: reporting-services

Another day, another problem: As soon as I add an footer on a RDLC-Report page, the Word-Renderer creates a empty line, no matter, which controls I add to the footer.
F.e. I added a textbox with the exact size of the footer and a border, but there is still an empty line AFTER the textbox-border.

Since there is no textbox or so for this empty line, I can't do some fancy stuff like setting the font-height to 0.

Is there a possibility to remove this empty line?

Comment: Have you checked the xml of the report for a <CR><LF> tag at that point in the report.

Comment: Hi, sadly there is nothing except for the textbox. I can't even Delete the row and it happens as well if I re-add the Footer.

Comment: Just for kicks have you attempted to narrow the width of the report to see if it is an overflow.